# Execute queries on SQL Server without having account

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Does anyone know is there a way for an application (that's connected to SQL Server) to make SQL queries to a database, but restricts the user from accessing directly to the database using SQL Server Management Studio?

Sorry, I know this sounds very confusing, but the reason I'm asking this is because at work, I'm using an application that allows me to enter data and upload it to the database. I assume a predefined `INSERT` sql script were loaded into the application, but when I log in to SQL Server Management Studio it won't let me use the `INSERT` statement at all. I was wondering why and how a application like this can programmed??

Any info or insight on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can't access the DB without an account. if you don't want the end-user to have direct login rights on the DB, then you create a dedicated account for your app. the app uses that account on BEHALF of the user.

Comment: Probably your application uses a specific Sql Server User and when you login with Sql Server Management Studio you are using a different user with different permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to access the database via SSMS without an error, the account can obviously access the database.  However, permissions will be limited to those granted to the account, either directly or via role membership.

It is likely the application is using a stored procedures to insert data if you are using the same account and your ad-hoc `INSERT` fails with an access is denied error.  When a stored procedure is used for data access, the invoking account needs execute permissions on the stored procedure but not the underlying tables.  Permissions on indirectly referenced objects are not evaluated as long as the ownership chain is unbroken.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for a more complete description of ownership chains.